# FFMPEG - Make a watermark in random position

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to implement the following loop:

1. Place logo.png in a random (x ,y) position of the video.
2. Make the logo fade out after 2 secods.
3. Wait 30 seconds and repeat.

After research in google I adapted different codes and got this this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]trim=0:30,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,loop=999:750:0,setpts=N/25/TB[w];[0][w]overlay=shortest=1:x=if(eq(mod(n\,200)\,0)\,sin(random(1))*w\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\,200)\,0)\,sin(random(1))*h\,y)" output.mp4
```

But it's not fully functional for my needs (and maybe there are commands I can remove). 
It only appear in a small random area on the top-left area of the video and not always fade out after 2 seconds.

What I should change to make it work?
Also, is it possible to reduce opacity of the logo.png or use a text instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to write a command that works, so I will post here in case someone needs.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontsize=10:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Text Here':x=if(eq(mod(n\,1200)\,0)\,rand(0\,(w-text_w))\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\,1200)\,0)\,rand(0\,(h-text_h))\,y):enable=lt(mod(n\,1200)\,200)" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

The parameter t\ was not working, that was my first problem using examples from ffmpeg documentation and from the answers in the community Stack.

Took me some time to noticed this issue. Maybe is something in Windows. So I just used n\ instead that is number of frames.

So now (x,y) change every 1200 frames

> x=if(eq(mod(n\,1200)\,0)\,rand(0\,(w-text_w))\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\,1200)\,0)\,rand(0\,(h-text_h))\,y)

Show text for 200 frames every 1200 frames

> enable=lt(mod(n\,1200)\,200)

Thanks for all help here!

Answer (score 1):

Another formulation which might work better comes from the Stack Overflow article
[ffmpeg - Dynamic letters and random position watermark to video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362443/ffmpeg-dynamic-letters-and-random-position-watermark-to-video).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5:text='studentname': \
 x=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(W-tw))\,x): \
 y=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(H-th))\,y)" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This will randomize the position every 30 seconds with no repeats.

Comment: I have seen that solution before, but this one has two things that I don't want. First is if 'studentnamehastoomanyletters' it stay in one big line, I couldn't break it in two lines (tried put \n).
Second, it does not fade out even if I use fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9

Comment: There is a second formulation in the same answer which you could try.

Comment: I did try actually, but I need random and fade out. I'm afraid some can be able to blur the positions if are fixed on video... Thanks for your help I will keep trying and accept new suggestions :)

Comment: Good luck, and I hope you are not up against an ffmpeg bug.

Comment: A bit busy now, will add an answer in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

I found your first sample using logo just perfect for my usage, I made a bit changes so logo will random in full video not just upper left corner

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]trim=0:30,fade=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,loop=999:750:0,setpts=N/25/TB[w];[0][w]overlay=shortest=1:x=if(eq(mod(n\,200)\,0)\,sin(random(1))*W\,x):y=if(eq(mod(n\,200)\,0)\,sin(random(1))*H\,y)" output.mpg
```